# How to add rows to radgrid on button click

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I want to load a page with radgrid headers and a button on top saying " Add new Course". I don't want to bind the radgrid to any datatsource. By clicking the button I need to add a row with textbox and dropdown controls(this binds from the datatbase) and each row should hold remove button. I've the below code. I have coded to the point where just the header and the button shows up. Also I don't want to see the "No record to display" message when the grid is empty. Below is my code. Any suggestion how it can be handled is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="AddCourses_RadGrid" RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="true" AllowDragToGroup="true" ReorderColumnsOnClient="true">
            <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true"></Scrolling>
            <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true" EnableRealTimeResize="true" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" TableLayout="Fixed" EnableHeaderContextMenu="true" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true">

            <Columns>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Course #"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Course Series"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Course Group"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Course Name"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddNew" runat="server" Text="Add New Course" OnClick="AddNewRow_Click" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>                        
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>               


            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            AddCourses_RadGrid.DataSource = string.Empty;              

        }
    }
```

Comment: You never want to show anything when the page loads?  Then just bind your grid to an empty list of your binding object.  After you've added records to the database, you can switch the datasource to the actual data you want to display.

Comment: I just need to show the headers of the grid and the Add new course button  on page load. On add new button click load the controls of the grid for the user to enter the details. likewise everythime the user clicks the button a new row with the controls showup. all the rows should have a remove button.